# Runtime 1004: OnTime _Application failed upon opening excel files enable edit

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

The error only appears if I open other excel workbook that needs to "enable edit" while running my macro.

Flow:
Userform.show (modeless) > opens Userform with a timer

The debugger points to these lines in Userform code:

```
Application.OnTime NextRun, "myTimer"
Application.OnTime NextRun, "myTimer", , False
```

I solved this problem by setting the Macro Security to:

- Enable all macros
- Uncheck trust access to the VBA...
- Uncheck ALL under Protected View tab

But I need a solution that doesn't involve users to change their macro settings.
Hope my explanation is clear.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this recently. `Application.OnTime` works fine if there is no open workbook, but not if the apparently active workbook is in protected view (since a protected view window can't be the active window).

I do a little test, and if it seems that a protected view window is in front, I create a new window temporarily, run the `Application.OnTime`, then close the temporary workbook.

```
' Fix: OnTime fails if "active" window is protected view
If Application.Windows.Count > 0 And ActiveWindow Is Nothing Then
    Dim bTempWkbk As Boolean
    bTempWkbk = True
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
End If
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"), "OnTimeFunction"
If bTempWkbk Then
    wb.Close False
End If
```